# Есть ли рабочий функциональный аудиоплеер для сайта с возможностью кастомизации оформления?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Есть ли рабочий функциональный аудиоплеер для сайта с возможностью кастомизации оформления?
В сети нашел такой плеер howler.js, но у него почему то криво работает функция циклического воспроизведения. После воспроизведения 1-го трека начинают воспроизводится одновременно 2, далее 3 и так далее треки. Можно ли как то это побороть, если нет, то есть ли рабочий функциональный аудиоплеер для сайта с возможностью кастомизации оформления (предыдущий трек, следующий, циклическое воспроизведение, регулировка громкости, возможность перемотки).

вот часть кода из демо.

```
var sound = new Howl({
 src: ['sound.webm', 'sound.mp3', 'sound.wav'],
 autoplay: true,
 loop: true,
 volume: 0.5,
 onend: function() {
   console.log('Finished!');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите самостоятельно кастомизировать оформление плеера, то возможно вам будет удобнее работать с нативным html5 элементом **< audio >**. Он поддерживает все что вам требуется. [Описание](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

Если вы хотите готовое решение, то вот [этот](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) плеер умеет, все что вам нужно.

Можете выбрать плеер из [этого](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-html5-audio-players/) списка, но там не все подойдет для вас.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такая js библиотека 
[audio.helper.js](https://audio-helper.tk), есть 2 темы, а также нехитрыми манипуляциями можно их изменить.

Answer (score 0):

Если не обязательно поддерживать mp3 (привет, Firefox) или есть желание *интересно* провести время с Flash'ом, то пилите сами.

Но лучше взять, например, [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) и кастомизировать его.

Comment: Firefox поддерживает mp3 при нормально установленных кодеках

Comment: @andreymal и вместо плеера пользователь увидит "Нормально установите кодеки"?